# Visual Studio 2015 Error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, source-control-explorer

My visual studio stopped working. When i try to open it shows me blank screen with error **Source Control Explorer. Parameter is Not valid** and no menu options.
tried uninstall and install, but still not working
[image: See The Error]

Answer (score 0):

Pleas try below things to narrow down the issue:

1, Clean TFS and VS caches, copy below commands ans save as `.bat` or `.cmd` file to run it.

```
SET AppDataTF=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
SET AppLocallVS=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
SET AppDataVS=%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio
IF EXIST "%AppDataTF%\4.0\Cache" rd /s /q "%AppDataTF%\4.0\Cache" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataTF%\5.0\Cache" rd /s /q "%AppDataTF%\5.0\Cache" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataTF%\6.0\Cache" rd /s /q "%AppDataTF%\6.0\Cache" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataTF%\7.0\Cache" rd /s /q "%AppDataTF%\7.0\Cache" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppLocallVS%\" rd /s /q "%AppDataTF%\" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataVS%\10.0\Team Explorer" rd /s /q "%AppDataVS%\10.0\Team Explorer" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataVS%\11.0\Team Explorer" rd /s /q "%AppDataVS%\11.0\Team Explorer" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataVS%\12.0\Team Explorer" rd /s /q "%AppDataVS%\12.0\Team Explorer" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataVS%\13.0\Team Explorer" rd /s /q "%AppDataVS%\13.0\Team Explorer" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataVS%\14.0\Team Explorer" rd /s /q "%AppDataVS%\14.0\Team Explorer" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataVS%\15.0\Team Explorer" rd /s /q "%AppDataVS%\15.0\Team Explorer" > NUL
```

2, Run below command to reset the devenv.exe /resetuserdata

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
devenv.exe /resetuserdata
```

3, If that still not work, just try to uninstall VS ( make sure you have removed all the components ), then reinstall VS.